# Summing a variable range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I'm needing to figure out how to sum a count who's length changes depending on criteria from other columns. I'm combining results from multiple spreadsheets.  There will be duplicates in Columns A & B that I need to group then add the Count in Columns C together to get a total for both and the total needs to be reflected on the last line of the grouping.   Source example:

```
Building#     Room#   Count    
1350          210      4    
1350          210      6    
1350          210      2    
1350          100      3    
1352          105      7    
1352          105      3    
1352          201      10
```

The results that I need to get needs to look like the below:

```
Building#     Room#   Count    Total    
1350          210      4    
1350          210      6    
1350          210      2        12    
1350          100      3         3    
1352          105      7    
1352          105      3        10    
1352          201      10       10
```

Comment: If you manually sort then a simple formula will get you the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula in D2 and pull it down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A3:$A$1048576,A2,B3:$B$1048576,B2)=0,SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Combo of yours and mine is probably the shortest: `=IF(OR(A2<>A3,B2<>B3),SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2),"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah yes, of course, if we assume sorted data. I was assuming non sorted data.

Comment: I'm trying to put this in a macro using VBA code, will this still work for workbooks that have 80,000 lines and some of the sorted combinations may be up to 200 instances?  I'm not going to know where a grouping will start and stop.

Comment: @BonnieZ I think you misunderstood how this site works. This is no code writing service. If you need it in VBA you will need to write that code yourself. But I recommend to use the formula (it will work for many rows, maybe takes some time to calculate, but it will work), then copy the total column and paste it as values in the same place (which converts formulas into values). Then filter by total column to get only the rows with a value `>0` (in column total) and copy/past the filtered data into a new sheet. done.

Comment: Also, forgot to add that once the like combos are summed Inam going to need to delete all but the last line of the grouping where the summation is noted to reduce the total lines to just one line  per grouping.  So il n this example I would end up with. 1350.  210.  12 for the 1st group.  1350. 100.  3 for 2nd group,  1352 105 10 for 3rd group, ect.  (Sorry for poor format, I'm typing this on my phone. Hope you get the idea though. )

Comment: @BonnieZ See my comment above. And please also review your old questions and mark the answers that helped you as solution. You might benefit from taking the [tour] to see how this site works. Grouping is done by sorting!

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't intending to treat this as a code writing service, I just wasn't sure how to translate the code into the RC format that VBA was needing but didn't realize that if I used the record macro option that it would change the letter/number cells references to the RC references in the formula.  I appreciate the help, the formula worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

IN D2 and pull down:

```
=IF(OR(A2<>A3,B2<>B3),SUM($C$2:C2)-SUM($D$1:D1),"")
```

[image]